# storing decimal number into computer with finite mantissa

Tags: numerical-methods, number-systems, floating-point

I am learning about numerical methods and the following link caught my attention:

> https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~mignotte/IFT2425/Disasters.html

So from what I understand 0.1 is not exactly representable in binary. But what about representing it in bases less than 10 other than base 2? Would that give the same result? I tried to research 0.1 representation in ternary but I didn't find much. Is there no base less than decimal base 10 that would give finite mantissa for 0.1?

My main question is in what base system a given decimal-based number like 0.1 can be represented with a finite mantissa? Is that even possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ironically, the explanation given for the Patriot missile disaster is not correct. The issue was never the accumulated rounding error, but the subtraction of a inaccurate number (24 bits) from less inaccurate one (48 bits). The correct explanation can be found here https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~arnold/disasters/Patriot-dharan-skeel-siam.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an exact representation of a number $x$ in base $\beta$ with finite mantissa means that we can write
$ x = n \beta^m $
where $n$ and $m$ are integers.

For the particular case $0.1$, that means we can write
$$ \frac{1}{10} = n \beta^m. $$

Multiply both sides by $10$ and divide by $\beta^m$:

$$ \beta^{-m} = 10n = 2 \cdot 5 \cdot n. $$

So $\beta^{-m}$ is an integer -- which is not a problem, just let $m \leq 0$ --
$\beta^{-m}$ is divisible by $2,$ and $\beta^{-m}$ is divisible by $5.$
As a consequence of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic,
$\beta$ must be divisible by $2$ and by $5$,
and therefore $\beta$ must be a multiple of $10.$

So $10$ is the smallest positive integer base in which to express $0.1$ exactly with a finite mantissa.

---

More generally, to find the smallest base in which a particular rational number is representable exactly with a finite mantissa,
express the number as a fraction in lowest terms.
Find the prime factors of the denominator.
The base you need is the product of all the distinct prime factors,
that is, if a prime occurs as a factor of the denominator more than once you only need to use it once in the base.